# How to draw path in Google maps V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to draw path in Google maps v2.

```
private void drawPath() {

    String arrayLatitude[] = { "13.019203", "13.019789", "13.020740",
            "13.021398", "13.022026", "13.022768", "13.024022",
            "13.024639", "13.025580", "13.026364" };

    String arrayLogitude[] = { "80.206267", "80.206342", "80.206385",
            "80.206407", "80.206407", "80.206536", "80.206815",
            "80.206922", "80.207072", " 0.207523" };


    ArrayList<LatLng> points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

    for (int j = 0; j < arrayLatitude.length; j++) {
        // HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

        double lat = Double.parseDouble(arrayLatitude[j]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(arrayLogitude[j]);
        LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        points.add(position);
    }       

    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; i++) {
      LatLng src = points.get(i);
      LatLng dest = points.get(i + 1);

      Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(
        new PolylineOptions().add(
          new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
          new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude)
        ).width(2).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true)
      );
    }
}
```

But when I do it like this the polyline is placed in my map, but at the end the straight line also created.
[image: Screen Image]

I don't want that extra line. Any ideas?

Comment: you can drow Direct line also you should have given latlong here to drow line at the place of road map or remove latlong of road map give his directions here in to drow line....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String arrayLatitude[] = { "13.019203", "13.019789", "13.020740",
            "13.021398", "13.022026", "13.022768", "13.024022",
            "13.024639", "13.025580", "13.026364" };

```
String arrayLogitude[] = { "80.206267", "80.206342", "80.206385",
        "80.206407", "80.206407", "80.206536", "80.206815",
        "80.206922", "80.207072", **" 0.207523"** };
```

Isn't it the reason? It looks like you wanted there 80.207523 for last longitude value.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```
ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            // traversing through routes
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(2);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }

            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Kat-hat.. Thanks for quick answer..  Here what is routes?? I have two array which is latitude and longitude? I have to change that array???

Comment: You may refer to this link http://javapapers.com/android/draw-path-on-google-maps-android-api/

Answer (score 0):

*Implement the below code*

```
    package com.mti.mtibusoperator;

        import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
    import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
    import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;
    import org.w3c.dom.Node;
    import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

    import android.util.Log;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

        public class GMapV2Direction {
            public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
            public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

            public GMapV2Direction() { }

            public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
                String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
                        + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
                        + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
                        + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode="+mode;

                Log.d("GoogleMapsDirection", url);
                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                    Document doc = builder.parse(in);
                    return doc;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
                Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
                return node2.getTextContent();
            }

            public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
                Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
                return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            }

            public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
                Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
                return node2.getTextContent();
            }

            public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(nl1.getLength() - 1);
                NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
                Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
                Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
                return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
            }

            public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
                Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
                Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
                return node1.getTextContent();
            }

            public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
                NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
                ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
                if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
                        Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
                        nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

                        Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                        double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                        Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                        double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                        listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

                        locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
                        ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
                        for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
                        }

                        locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
                        nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
                        latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
                        lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
                        lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
                        lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
                        listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
                    }
                }

                return listGeopoints;
            }

            private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
                for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
                    if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
                        return i;
                }
                return -1;
            }

            private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
                ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
                int lat = 0, lng = 0;
                while (index < len) {
                    int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
                    do {
                        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                    } while (b >= 0x20);
                    int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                    lat += dlat;
                    shift = 0;
                    result = 0;
                    do {
                        b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                        result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                        shift += 5;
                    } while (b >= 0x20);
                    int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
                    lng += dlng;

                    LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
                    poly.add(position);
                }
                return poly;
            }
        }
// Draw line between source and destination
private void drawRoute(final LatLng start, final LatLng end) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<LatLng>>() {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            @Override
            protected ArrayList<LatLng> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Document doc = md.getDocument(start, end, GMapV2Direction.MODE_DRIVING);
                System.out.println("document "+doc);
                if(doc != null) {
                    ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint  = md.getDirection(doc);
                    return directionPoint;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
                /*int duration = md.getDurationValue(doc);
                String distance = md.getDistanceText(doc);
                String start_address = md.getStartAddress(doc);
                String copy_right = md.getCopyRights(doc);*/

            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(directionPoint);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if(directionPoint != null && directionPoint .size() > 0) {
                    PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.RED);

                    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
                        rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
                    }

                    mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
                }
            }



        }.execute();

    }
```

Comment: Pass the LatLng object to drawRoute method for eg: drawRoute(new LatLng(src.latitude, src.longitude),
          new LatLng(dest.latitude,dest.longitude))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This may help me to another screen.